# TF-IDF weighted fasttext word embeddings

Tags: nlp, data-science, tf-idf, word-embedding, fasttext

How to calculate the weighted average of fasttext word embedded per word level using TF-IDF weights in python, so the produced output is a vector of fatstext multiple by the weights from TF-IDF

I expect produced output to be a vector of fatstext multiple by the weights from TF-IDF for each word

Comment: It'd be helpful if you provided an example showing your word levels so we can know what type of average you're talking about.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of <https://stackoverflow.com/q/77259467/130288>. If you're not getting useful responses, it's better to improve your original question than post a redundant question with the same deficiencies. Being clear about what language you're using, what you've tried so far, and what's proven confusing is beter than simply asking others to code a generic example for you with incomplete specs.